# Intersection of Two Lines

Tags: code-golf, geometry

Given equation of two lines in the format Ax+By=C, determine their intersection point. If they are parallel print 'parallel' without quotes. For input/output format refer sample input/output.

```
Input
1x+1y=1
1x-1y=1

Output
(1.00,0.00)

Input
0x+1y=0
1x+0y=0

Output
(0.00,0.00)
```

1. -1000000 <= A,B,C <= 1000000.
2. Note their intersection point may not be integer. Print upto two decimal places.
3. Shortest solution wins.

Comment: Is a function call valid? example : f[1x+1y=1, 1x-1y=1]

Comment: @belisarius Yes, but the solution should be entire program.

Comment: Is the format always `Ax+By=C` or can it also be `Ax-By=C` or even `-Ax+By=C`? Are negative numbers for A, B or C even allowed? »Print up to two decimal places« implies that less can be printed, your examples do not suggest that. If the output is locale-dependent (which can happen with plenty languages in formatted output), can we assume `en-US` or `C` as locale? (I.e. anything that uses a decimal point and not a comma).

Comment: @Joey Yes A,B and C can be negative. `Ax-By=C` is already given in one of the examples. The points should have 2 decimal places.

Comment: @Joey Edited the question to show that. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: I know this is an old question, but can we take input as two lists containing `[A,B,C]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Ruby - 119 chars

```
a,b,c,d,e,f=(gets+gets).scan(/-?\d+/).map &:to_f
puts (t=a*e-b*d)==0?'parallel':"(%.2f,%.2f)"%[(e*c-b*f)/t,(a*f-c*d)/t]
```

Comment: It's odd but my ruby 1.9.x shows `-0.00`, :-\ and you can use `gets(p)` instead of 2 `gets`, it will read the entire contents (assuming it was piped)

Comment: `gets(2)` would get two bytes of input, as opposed to two lines on input.

Answer (score 3):

### Python, <strike>148</strike> 146 chars

```
import re
I=raw_input
a,b,p,c,d,q=eval(re.sub('x|y=','.,',I()+','+I()))
D=a*d-b*c
print'(%.2f,%.2f)'%((p*d-q*b)/D,(a*p-c*q)/D)if D else'parallel'
```

Answer (score 2):

### Python+sympy - 161 chars

```
from sympy import*
x,y=symbols('xy')
e=lambda:eval(raw_input().replace('x','*x').replace('y=','*y-'))
r=solve([e(),e()],[x,y])
print r and`r[x],r[y]`or'parallel'
```

**Python+sympy - 143 chars (different output format)**

```
from sympy import*
x,y=symbols('xy')
e=lambda:eval(raw_input().replace('x','*x').replace('y=','*y-'))
print solve([e(),e()],[x,y])or'parallel'
```

output format for 143 char version is slightly different from the spec

```
In:
1x+1y=1
1x-1y=1

Out:
{x: 1, y: 0}

In:
0x+1y=0
1x+0y=0

Out:
{x: 0, y: 0}
```

Answer (score 2):

### [sage](http://sagemath.org/) - 162 chars

```
x,y=var('x,y')
e=lambda:eval(raw_input().replace('x','*x').replace('y','*y='))
try:r=solve([e(),e()],[x,y])[0];print`r[0].rhs(),r[1].rhs()`
except:print'parallel'
```

Answer (score 2):

### J, <strike>146</strike> <strike>132</strike> <strike>134</strike> 124

```
echo'parallel'"_`(1|.')(',[:(,',',])&(0j2&":)/[:,,.@{:%.}:)@.([:*@|[:-/ .*}:)|:".>{.`(<@}:@;@(1 2&{))`{:(`:0)"1;:;._2(1!:1)3
```

Parsing this is awful.

**Edit**: Realized that my output is basically broken, although it works for the examples given and parallels...

**Edit**: Posting the shorter version I already had.

**Edit**: Fixed without too much pain...

**Edit**: Fixed a weird issue where the program was spread across multiple lines.

Somewhat ungolfed version:

```
words =: ;:;._2(1!:1)3
NB. Leverage J's parser itself to split each line into e.g. ax + by = c
lines =: ".>{.`(<@}:@;@(1 2&{))`{:(`:0)"1 words
NB. Use a 3-part gerund (`) to get boxed strings 'ax';'b';'c', unbox and parse
calc_and_format =: 1|.')(',[:(,',',])&(0j2&":)/[:,,.@{:%.}:
NB. %. (matrix multiply) first two rows (a d/b e) by third row turned (c/f)
NB. And then format laboriously. 0j2&": formats numbers with 2 decimals.
det_nonzero =: [:*@|[:-/ .*}:
NB. 1 if determinant (-/ .*) of (a b/d e) is nonzero (*@|)
echo'parallel'"_`calc_and_format@.det_nonzero|: lines
NB. transpose parsed input to get (a d/b e/c f). 
NB. If det_nonzero, call calc_and_format, otherwise constant 'parallel'
NB. Print
```

Answer (score 2):

## OCaml + Batteries, 163 characters

As straightforward as it gets:

```
Scanf.scanf"%fx%fy=%f\n%fx%fy=%f\n"Float.(fun a b c d e
f->Printf.(fun u->if u=0.then printf"parallel"else
printf"(%.2f,%.2f)"((b*f-c*e)/u)((d*c-a*f)/u))(b*d-a*e))
```

**Edit:**

- Initial version, <strike>169</strike>
- Use Batteries for delimited overloading of operators, 164
- Lambda binding of `u`, 163

Answer (score 2):

### C-149 bytes

Not much of golfing just the basics.

```
float a,b,c,d,m,n,t;main(){scanf("%fx%fy=%f%fx%fy=%f",&a,&b,&m,&c,&d,&n);t=b*c-a*d;t?printf("(%.2f,%.2f)",(b*n-d*m)/t,(c*m-a*n)/t):puts("parallel");}
```

[Here](http://ideone.com/68538) is the ideone link for testing.

Instead of printing 'parallel' an alternative could be to print the orthogonal distance between the lines when they are parallel.

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 10 bytes

```
∆Q:[vt|`ċ₃
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLiiIZROlt2dHxgxIvigoMiLCIiLCIxeCsxeT0xXG4xeC0xeT0xIl0=)

[8 if the format can be `` ⟨ ⟨ `x` | xval ⟩ | ⟨ `y` | yval ⟩ ⟩ ``](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLiiIZROsKsw59gxIvigoMiLCIiLCIxeCsxeT0xXG4xeC0xeT0xIl0=)
. Returns fraction representation of all numbers if not integer.

### Explained

```
∆Q:[vt|`ċ₃
∆Q          # Solve the two input equations simultaneously
  :[        # If there's a solution
    vt      #   get the last values of each two item tuple
      |`ċ₃  # else, push the string "parallel"
```

Comment: In Vyxal, can we not close If Statement?

Comment: @lesobrod that's right. You don't need to if it's at the end of a program